# Communication Protocol between a Drone and USRP

Tags: labview, gnuradio, usrp

I am working on a project wherein a signal (preferably ISM) will be sent by a Hackrf one module mounted on a drone. The SNR of the transmitted signal will be calculated by a USRP 2900 placed on the ground. If the calculated SNR is below a certain percentage or a value, then the drone should lower its height; otherwise, it should hover at the same height.
I want to ask is how I can make a link between the USRP on the ground and the drone to achieve this? What are the hardware and software I will need for this?

Comment: you have already defined the hardware you have; so, in addition to your two SDRs, you'll need a computer for the Hackrf on the drone, and one for the USRP on the ground. The rest is learning how to build your first SDR application. Also, labview and GNU Radio are mutually exclusive, so you'll have to pick one. I'm removing your [tag:mavlink] tag, because what you're building has zero relationship to mavlink.

Comment: Note that if this is for altitude control, it's a bad idea, for geometrical reasons: in free space propagation,. signal loss is a function of *distance*, not height. Pythagoras applies! Also, close to ground or buildings, or any other RF-reflective structure, multipath will make things very hard, and your approach guarantees that your drone disappears behind buildings as soon as the building absorbs a bit of the signal power. All in all, not a great idea.

Comment: Can you please comment on how can I develop the feedback link between USRP and the drone? By the way thanks for your earlier response

Comment: depends on your drone's own controller. Better drones use encrypted comms, so all your efforts would be in vain and you'd just need to fall back to the drone vendor's own remote control and the SDK they offer.